# Golang - struct : time.Time

Tags: datetime, go

I am trying to cast a value to a struct which has a type of time.Time.

The value is:

```
t := time.Now()
format := "2006-01-02 15:04:05"
```

Then I am trying to put this into the struct:

```
response.SetAppData[0].LiveDate = time.Parse(format, t.String())
```

However I get the error of:

```
controllers/apps.go:1085: multiple-value time.Parse() in single-value context
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that [`time.Parse`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse) returns two results `time.Time` and `error` values. You are assigning only to one variable.

You should do that:

```
response.SetAppData[0].LiveDate, err = time.Parse(format, t.String())
if err != nil {
    // error handling here
}
```

Comment: So this works, but the response I get is not what I am expecting. I just want to cast the value e.g. 2016-04-04 13:33:00 into the Struct.